# glReadPixels does not work with non-square width and height?

Tags: opencv, opengl

Currently what is on my viewport is :

[image]

Here is my export image method.

```
void exportImage()
{
  int width = 200;
  int height = 100;
  GLubyte *data = new GLubyte[4*width*height];
  glReadPixels(0,0,width,height,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
  cv::Mat imageMat(width, height, CV_8UC4, data);
  cv::flip(imageMat, imageMat, 0);
  cv::imwrite("ok.jpg",imageMat);
}
```

When use 800x800, (please don't mind yellow becoming blue)

[image]

When use 200x200,

[image]

But when use 200x100,

```
void exportImage()
{
  int width = 200;
  int height = 100;
  GLubyte *data = new GLubyte[4*width*height];
  glReadPixels(0,0,width,height,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
  cv::Mat imageMat(width, height, CV_8UC4, data);
  cv::flip(imageMat, imageMat, 0);
  cv::imwrite("ok.jpg",imageMat);
}
```

[image]

First of all width became height, and the image is wrong. It looks like array index shifting problem, but I could not understand why because the allocation should change depending on width and height also according to the code.

When I tried swapping width and height in `glReadPixels` :

```
void exportImage()
{
  int width = 200;
  int height = 100;
  GLubyte *data = new GLubyte[4*width*height];
  glReadPixels(0,0,height,width,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
  cv::Mat imageMat(width, height, CV_8UC4, data);
  cv::flip(imageMat, imageMat, 0);
  cv::imwrite("ok.jpg",imageMat);
}
```

[image]

The image looks correct? But the width and height still swapped??

Comment: You say "180x200", but the screenshot says "190x200".  What's up with that?

Comment: Oh, it's a mistype. The information in the screenshot is correct.

Comment: Wait a minute, I actually put 190 in the "height" but why it came out as width..? Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: I have edited the question with 200x100 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made a very stupid mistake. `glReadPixels` is actually fine, but the cv::Mat's initialization corresponds to rows x cols which means height x width. So with that swapped, the output looks fine now.

```
void exportImage()
{
  int width = 200;
  int height = 100;
  GLubyte *data = new GLubyte[4*width*height];
  glReadPixels(0,0,width,height,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
  cv::Mat imageMat(height, width, CV_8UC4, data);
  cv::flip(imageMat, imageMat, 0);
  cv::imwrite("ok.jpg",imageMat);
}
```

[image]